# Gandi + SwiftMailer on Symfony4

Tags: php, symfony, email, smtp, swiftmailer

I apologize in advance for posting a Nth question about symfony4 swiftmailer, but as I've never been able to send an email with it, I think my problems might be somewhere else from symfony. (nb: In the end I need to make it work with GANDI, but I'm trying first with GMAIL as more topic are related).

Docs: [GANDI SMTP CONF](https://docs.gandi.net/en/gandimail/standard_email_settings/index.html#general-configuration-settings)

At least here is my configuration (.env)

```
APP_ENV=prod (tried all with DEV too)
...
#MAILER_URL=gmail://****@gmail.com:****@localhost
#MAILER_URL=smtp://smtp.gmail.com:587?encryption=tls&username=****&password=****
#MAILER_URL=smtp://mail.gandi.net:25?encryption=tls&auth_mode=login&username=****&password=****
#MAILER_URL=smtp://mail.gandi.net:25?encryption=ssl&auth_mode=login&username=****&password=****
#MAILER_URL=smtp://mail.gandi.net:465?encryption=ssl&auth_mode=login&username=****&password=****
MAILER_URL=smtp://mail.gandi.net:587?encryption=tls&auth_mode=login&username=****&password=****
```

I tried also directly in the swiftmailer.yaml

```
swiftmailer:
    transport:        gmail
    username:         ****@gmail.com
    password:         *******
    host:             localhost
    port:             465
    encryption:       ssl
    auth-mode:        login
    spool: { type: 'memory' }
    stream_options:
        ssl:
            allow_self_signed: true
            verify_peer: false
            verify_peer_name: false
```

I indeed have setted my google account to **enable less secure application**. All the gmail request return

> Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.

-> I am 100% sure that my gmail password and account are right.

My Gandi request returns

> Expected response code 354 but got code "554", with message "554 5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients " [] []

-> Here is the php code to send email:

```
$message = (new \Swift_Message('Test'))
        ->setFrom('****@****.com')
        ->setTo('****@gmail.com')
        ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
                'email/view.html.twig',
                ['name' => '****', 'surname' => '****']
            ),
            'text/html'
        );

    try {
        $result = $mailer->send($message);
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
    }
```

So I do have a recipient & sender..

I'm working locally on a Macbook, is there any soft that could prevent email from leaving, or corrupting the email I send ?

Comment: Try changing your Gmail password and then again try and send the e-mail.

Comment: I switched email but nothing changed, then I created a new gmailAccount to make a test, and now it is working. I don't really know why my account is blocked.. But now it is working with GMAIL. I still have the same problem with GANDI: **Expected response code 354 but got code "554", with message "554 5.5.1 Error: no valid recipients**. No one seems to have a similar problem with gandi..

Comment: I have the same problem using Gandi mail with the config `.env` `MAILER_URL=smtp://mail.gandi.net:465?encryption=ssl&username=example@mail.com&password=password. I can't send mail. Only Gmail work.. Did you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The SMTP error message would indicate that the email address you're trying to send to (or from) might be invalid. Ensure that the email addresses are actual valid inboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your password don't contain any reserved chars like `! * ' ( ) ; : @ & = + $ , / ?# |`.

Here my config with Gandi mail and Swiftmailer work.

`swiftmailer.yaml`

```
swiftmailer:
    url: '%env(MAILER_URL)%'
    spool: { type: 'memory' }
```

Careful, in local, you need to delete `spool: { type: 'memory'}` to send the email messages immediately.

`.env`

```
MAILER_URL=smtp://mail.gandi.net:465?encryption=ssl&auth_mod=login&username=user@mail.com&password=password1234
```

Besides you can try your config directly with this command line : `php bin/console swiftmailer:email:send`

Comment: Nice approach, but in case you send many emails at once (for example a newsletter function)- you need to use the mail spool function, otherwise you might run into "not enough memory exception".